# Event when user clicks to close message window

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

Is there a way to know when a user clicks to close the message window and **before** the "do you want to save changes" dialog shows up? I've registered to the Inspector.Close event but it fires only **after** the user has decided to save/discard the changes:
`((InspectorEvents_10_Event)Inspector).Close += OnInspectorClose;`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006948/vb-net-outlook-2010-add-in-how-to-listen-to-inspector-close-event-mail-item

Comment: I've seen that but can't see how it solves my problem.

Comment: Just a thought: It seems like saving the message will prevent the dialog from displaying (it only displays when there exist unsaved changes to the mailitem). You can then delete it after the close event fires.

Comment: Hmmm, I can't save the message for security reasons but I guess I can't do much more with Outlook (I guess there's no "CloseStarted" event?). Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: I was looking to see if there was an analog to the QueryClose event (this is a PowerPoint presentation event that basically fires *before* the actual presentation.Close event...) but it doesn't look like there is one.

Comment: There are security protocols that allow your add-in to *send* messages, but not to save them as drafts?  Weird, but OK...

Comment: Yes, once you send the message nobody can sniff it off your hard drive (unlike when you save it). Either way, I think I found the event I was looking for. It's not a member of the Inspector class but the MailItem: `((ItemEvents_10_Event)item).Close += OnItemClose`. Now need to figure out how to prepare the event handler.

Comment: huh? the `Save` event doesn't save the message to disk AFAIK -- it saves to an Outlook folder. Sending a message (usually, but not always) also saves a copy of the message to an Outlook "Sent" folder.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so apparently I need to use the event from the mail item, not the inspector. I need to register the handler inside eg. the NewInspector handler:

```
if (inspector.CurrentItem is MailItem)
{
  MailItem item = inspector.CurrentItem as MailItem;
  ((ItemEvents_10_Event)item).Close += OnItemClose;
}
```

And then prepare the handler:

```
private void OnItemClose(ref bool cancel) //ItemEvents_10_CloseEventHandler
{
  ((ItemEvents_10_Event)_lastOpenedItem).Close -= OnItemClose;
  _lastOpenedItem.Close(OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);
}
```

And this OnItemClose will execute before the Inspector's Close event fires (`((InspectorEvents_10_Event)Inspector).Close`).